# How to create search engine in php in my web page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xwm390o5/4/): In my jsfiddle link, It didn't apply my styles, and also If i put such word like bootstrap, and hit enter, it happens nothing.I need something like [this](http://www.gatesnotes.com/Search?search=aa),

html:

```
<div class="autocomplete-w1">
   <form action='' method='post'>
    <p><label>Country:</label>
        <input id="autocompleteInput" type='text' name='country' value='' class='auto'/>
    </p>
    </form>
  </div>
```

May i know, how to achieve this one, Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) In the fiddle, there's nothing with class="autocomplete" that the styles can apply to. 2) The form doesn't have an action. Also, you have misspelled Bootstrap.

Comment: I used class name called autocomplete-w1.. but it is not working, thanks